# Cannot be Provided Without an @Provides-annotated Method

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

There have been many other similar questions, but none of the answers have been applicable to my code. I cannot figure out what I have done wrong.

First I have a `NetworkModule` that is used as a module for the `ApplicationComponent`:

```
@Module
open class NetworkModule {

    companion object {
        private val BASE = "http://www.example.com/"
    }

    @Provides @ApplicationScope
    fun provideClient(): OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient()

    @Provides @ApplicationScope
    fun provideMoshi(): Moshi {
        return Moshi.Builder().add(InstantAdapter).add(UriAdapter).build()
    }

    @Provides @ApplicationScope
    fun provideRetrofit(client: OkHttpClient, moshi: Moshi): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder().client(client).baseUrl(BASE)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
                .build()
    }

    @Provides @ApplicationScope
    fun provideArticleService(retrofit: Retrofit): ArticleService {
        return retrofit.create(ArticleService::class.java)
    }

}
```

---

```
@ApplicationScope @Component(modules = arrayOf(ContextModule::class, RealmModule::class, NetworkModule::class))
interface ApplicationComponent {}
```

Then the `ApplicationComponent` is built in my `Application` class:

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        AndroidThreeTen.init(this)

        plantLog()
        drawDagger()
    }

    private fun drawDagger() {
        Injector.initializeApplicationComponent(this)
    }

    // ...

}
```

---

```
object Injector {

    lateinit var applicationComponent: ApplicationComponent
        private set

    fun initializeApplicationComponent(context: Context) {
        applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .contextModule(ContextModule(context))
                .networkModule(NetworkModule())
                .realmModule(RealmModule())
                .build()
    }

    // ...

}
```

Then I have an `ActivityModule` that is used in the `ActivityComponent` (which has `ApplicationComponent` as a dependency):

```
@Module
open class ActivityModule(private val activity: AppCompatActivity) {

    @Provides @ActivityScope @ActivityContext
    fun provideContext(): Context = activity

    @Provides @ActivityScope
    fun provideFragmentManager(): FragmentManager = activity.supportFragmentManager

}
```

---

```
@ActivityScope @Component(dependencies = arrayOf(ApplicationComponent::class), modules = arrayOf(ActivityModule::class))
interface ActivityComponent {

    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)

}
```

Finally, I create a new `ActivityComponent` in the `MainActivity` and `@Inject` the `ArticleService`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var service: ArticleService

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
                .applicationComponent(Injector.applicationComponent)
                .activityModule(ActivityModule(this))
                .build().inject(this)

        service.getNewsArticles()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .subscribe(
                        { response -> onNext(response) },
                        { error -> onError(error) })
    }

    // ...

}
```

But when I try to build I get the following error, even though I believe the `provideArticleService()` function in `NetworkModule` is annotated correctly:

> ArticleService cannot be provided without an @Provides- or
>   @Produces-annotated method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the provision methods to inherit to your Activity scoped component.  Either use subcomponents instead of component dependency, or define the provision methods in your application component.

```
 @ApplicationScope @Component(modules = arrayOf(ContextModule::class, RealmModule::class, NetworkModule::class))
 interface ApplicationComponent {
      ArticleService articleService();
 }
```